# Create button on fixed width panel programmatically c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I create a panel on page left. I added buttons(image-top and text-bottom) on this panel programmatically. Panel's width fixed and when I set the button's height, if text is so long, image and text overlap. But I don't know added button's height.

I add this buttons like

```
btnFav.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 50);
```

[image]

when I write Autosize show like this,

[image]

by the way,

```
btnFav.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
btnFav.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

Comment: You need to show some code, so that someone can try pointing the problem.

Comment: Insert a TableLayout with two rows inside the panel and place buttons on it.

Comment: I used but again text and image overlap when I writed autosize

Answer (score 0):

Why not a custom control?
Very easy to do, just specify a rectangle where the text needs to be placed, and place the image next to it or ontop or under.

EG.

overriding the onpaint() method

```
Rectangle textRect = new Rectangle(0, Height / 2, Width, Height / 2);
e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, Brush, textRect, StringAlignment);
e.Graphics.DrawImage(MyImage, 0, 0);
```

This will place the image above the text, also a much cleaner way of operating